# Alternative to waiting for child_process to quit node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I've got these 2 codes running in 1 script:

The ping script:

```
app.get("/ping", function(req, res) {
    res.send("Pong!");
});
```

And a work in progress youtube downloader:

```
app.post("/nodedl", function(req, res) {
 res.write("===Gradyncore listnener===\n")
 res.write("Recived POST request from "+req.ip+" to /nodedl\n")
 res.write("POST(url): "+req.body.url+"\n")
 res.write("checking key...\n")
 if (req.body.key==="<Insert key here>"){
   res.write("Key is valid! Skipping pre-download script...\n")
 } else {
   res.write("Key is invalid. Running pre-download script...\n")
   exec("/home/gradyn/website/projects/nodeDL/scripts/check.sh", function (error, results) {
   if (results != null) {
        res.write(results+"\n");
   } else if (error != null) {
        res.write("Error: " + error+"\n");
  }
});
 }
res.end();
});
```

The problem is, by the time check.sh finishes, `res.end();` has allredy been emitted, causing this error followed by a crash

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write after end
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:439:15)
    at /home/gradyn/listener/app.js:29:13
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)
```

I'm fairly new to node.js,  but from what I understand, If i wait for the child process to complete before calling res.end(), the entire script (including the ping listener) will not work until the child process completes.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that your exec is asynchronous, code below it won't wait to for completion of exec and get executed... You have to end response inside callback function:

```
app.post("/nodedl", function(req, res) {
    res.write("===Gradyncore listnener===\n")
    res.write("Recived POST request from "+req.ip+" to /nodedl\n")
    res.write("POST(url): "+req.body.url+"\n")
    res.write("checking key...\n")
    if (req.body.key==="<Insert key here>"){
        res.write("Key is valid! Skipping pre-download script...\n")
    } else {
       res.write("Key is invalid. Running pre-download script...\n")
       exec("/home/gradyn/website/projects/nodeDL/scripts/check.sh", function(error, results) {
           if (results != null) {
               res.write(results+"\n");
               res.end();
           } else if (error != null) {
               res.write("Error: " + error+"\n");
               res.end();
           }
        });
    }
});
```